# Tell Javascript code whether the App is running in remote host or localhost

Tags: javascript

I have a host name in **javascript** function and use Ajax to send **JSON** to server, I test it in **localhost** and I upload to remote host to test again.

Everytime I upload my web app to remote host and I need to manually change the host name to remote host name to test it, 
localhost => mydomain.com

I have to change it back if I test it in my local machine.
mydomain.com => localhost

BTW, the font end is **Javascript** **Html CSS**, The backend is not Node.js and Not **javascript**. (It is Haskell)

I'm wondering how to tell my **javascript** code I'm running my App. in remote host or I'm running my App. in **localhost** so that my **javascript** can use different **hostname** in the code.

My current solution is I get the OS name in the backend code, and create

```
<div id='myid'>OS_Name</div>
```

and hide in my html page, and my **javascript function** read the 'id=myid' to get the OS_Name so my **javascript** code can distinct **localhost** or remote host.

I'm sure there better solution for this problem.

Can anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just look at `window.location.host` variable. You can put it in your console to experiment.

Comment: If server and api run in the same client, try to use relative paths instead.

Comment: environment variables... use them, love them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to get the base url of where you app is running in node.  So instead of constantly changing `localhost` to `mydomain.com` and back again, you can use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`.